# How to type React.useState() which can get multiple types as its value with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to type useState() hook which can get number and string type as its value.

```
export interface Select {
  selectValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number | string>>;
  ...
}
```

And I'm trying to use above component like this,

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
<Select selectValue = {setValue} />
```

But It gives me this Error.

```
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | number>>'.
  Type 'SetStateAction<string | number>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<number>'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<number>'.
```

How can I resolve this Error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to provide a generic type argument to `useState<T>` like this:

```ts
const [value, setValue] = useState<string | number>(0);
```

Otherwise, it will infer the type from your initial value `0` which is only `number`. Here's a complete example:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwLACg5wCYFMBmBDAVwBt48BnOAJSzwGMYAaVdAEWDLDxloAsm0qNegFEiWEFgB2jZnADKWGHJhcsAQXrAIk-ugJksy1fwC+cHFAgg4AcihCYNgNypUwaVij5aWeVjH0AAqWYBTIAgYBMABqeEQEWABccGQwUO4A5nAAPnCSBCAARp4uEYoKUbHxSXBsHFy8ADwKSiow6prajanpklm5+UWeAHzDpSauKNi0RHj25gSSnZJ+UXAAFGAhZMkVWEHbAJTJ1HQwouJSMKWoOIvLcMIAHnjgYhvHgmcXEtKIsrRtKk4ABtABucQSDBSiiqCQAunAALxwfSGNpYbppTI5PIFYpQYbrAAMh1K6HsMAIUBWzX8+3gkQZcKwSIQEOqZgMSnp9BZbO5LLMAHoxqgJiggA)

```ts
import {
  default as React,
  Dispatch,
  ReactElement,
  SetStateAction,
  useState,
} from 'react';

interface SelectProps {
  selectValue: string | number;
  setSelectValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | number>>;
}

declare function Select (props: SelectProps): ReactElement;

function Example (): ReactElement {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | number>(0);
  return <Select selectValue={value} setSelectValue={setValue} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break it down so its like this:

```
export interface Select {
  selectValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>> | React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
  ...
}
```

Also why are you passing the setValue, did you mean to pass the value itself? (`<Select selectValue = {value} />`)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check what the `<Select>` component's `selectValue` callback passes in the arguments. It might not be passing a number that is expected in the `setValue` method.